# Accessing DB connection with a Go Discord bot without global variables?

Tags: postgresql, go, discord

I am currently creating a Discord bot in Go that performs queries on a PostGreSQL database whenever it receives valid input from users.

```
func checkNilErr(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        log.Panic(e)
    }
}

func InitDb() (*sql.DB, error) { 
    db, err := dbRepo.SqlConfig(ConnectionStr) 
    return db, err 
}

func Run() {
    // create a discord session
    discord, err := discordgo.New("Bot " + BotToken)
    checkNilErr(err)
    
    postGres, postGresErr := InitDb()
    defer postGres.Close() // close postGres connection after function termination
    checkNilErr(postGresErr)
    
    postGresRepo = dbRepo.NewCardRepo(postGres)
    
    // add an event handler. Queries to the db are performed whenever the bot        
    //receives valid user input
    discord.AddHandler(newMessage)
    
    //Send intents to discord servers
    discord.Identify.Intents = discordgo.IntentsAllWithoutPrivileged
    
    // open session
    err = discord.Open()
    checkNilErr(err)
    defer discord.Close() // close session, after function termination
    
    // keep bot running untill there is NO os interruption (ctrl + C)
    fmt.Println("Bot running....")
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM, os.Interrupt)
    <-c
}
```

My largest pain point is the discord.AddHandler(newMessage) function. AddHandler is the function that determines how the bot will respond to valid user input. Unfortunately, It will only accept the following arguments:

```
func(s *discordgo.Session, m *discordgo.MessageCreate)
func(s *discordgo.Session, m *discordgo.PresenceUpdate)
```

This is annoying as I cannot pass in the initialized DB connection as an argument. The only way around this issue I can think of is to either:

1. Use global variables. I will do whatever it takes to avoid this.
2. Perform the db connection initialization within AddHandler. This will cause the bot to reconnect and disconnect to the database every time it receives valid user input, which is far from ideal.

I have tried looking into repository interface patterns, but it has not solved my problem. Is there a way to access the initialized DB connection from within AddHandler without the use of global variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AddHandler`, you can pass a method defined on a type, and that type should have objects that need to be accessed within the handler execution.

Here is the sample code

```
type Bot struct {
    DB   *sql.DB
    Name string
}

func (bot *Bot) ReadyHandler(s *discordgo.Session, r *discordgo.Ready) {
    log.Printf("Bot  %v is up! \n", bot.Name)
}

func (bot *Bot) MessageHandler(s *discordgo.Session, r *discordgo.MessageCreate) {
    log.Println("inside MessageCreate")
}

func (bot *Bot) UpdateHandler(s *discordgo.Session, r *discordgo.PresenceUpdate) {
    log.Println("inside PresenceUpdate")
}

func Run() {
    db, err := InitDb()
    checkNilErr(err)

    // Init the bot handler with the required data
    bot := Bot{
        DB:   db,
        Name: "my-custom-bot",
    }
    // create a discord session
    discord, err := discordgo.New("Bot " + botToken)
    checkNilErr(err)
    discord.AddHandler(bot.ReadyHandler)

    // Rest of your codes
}
```

By this you can access your db within the methods and the db initialize only once.

You can also try like this

```
func (bot *Bot) ReadyHandler() func(s *discordgo.Session, m *discordgo.Ready) {
    return func(s *discordgo.Session, m *discordgo.Ready) {
        log.Printf("Bot  %v is up! \n", bot.Name)
    }
}

discord.AddHandler(bot.ReadyHandler())
```

Hope this helps